# Docker PostgreSQL: initialization scripts

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have copied a test mydb.sql to the directory

```
/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

and it works fine.

Now I'd like to create my demo db and insert data. I have

```
mydb_1_struct.sql -- there is db structure
mydb_2_data.sql -- there is db data
```

I need to execute these scripts in strong order: structure and then data.
What is the order of the scripts execution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docker-entrypoint script](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/docker-entrypoint.sh)
it process the scripts   in alphabetical order  :

> docker_process_init_files /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*

So you can just  use the method you mention  ( mydb_1 , mydb_2 ) etc.